Flask MongoEngine ListField(StringField) error
`
from .db import db
class Movie(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    casts = db.ListField(db.StringField(), required=True)
    genres = db.ListField(db.StringField(), required=True)`

in flask when trying to do db.ListField(db.StringField(), required=True)
I get an error like
    casts = db.ListField(db.StringField(), required=True) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: WtfFieldMixin.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
then tried
casts = db.ListField(required=True)
and it works.
But I need list of string in model. how to do it?

try this db.ListField(db.StringField(required=True))
